# CSS - Background Color On Flexbox Grid - Column Layout - Top Row, First Column

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is the link to the codepen:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/jdiapps/pen/JNwXPx)

I want to change the background color of the top row and first column.

See the attached codepen for the css and html.

I am doing: but the blue is not going across the entire row.

```css
.Grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word !important;  
}
.Grid-column {
  //flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding:0;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-wrap: break-word !important; 
  
}
.Grid-cell {
   width: 100%;
   flex: 1;
   word-wrap: break-word !important;   
   min-width: 50%;
  padding:0 1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.Grid-cell:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: lightgray;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;   
}  

.Grid-row:first-child {
  background:dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.Grid-cell:first-child {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top:1em;
}
.Grid-cell:first-child {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id=event-history-view>
    <div class="Grid">
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">1Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Brief Descriptionasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-column">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This: `div.Grid-row{ padding:0;}` will make it span across, but I am not sure that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Question: How can I adjust each cell so that the x-axis (rows) adjust dynamically to the text. Notice that the text 2Brief Descriptionasdfasdf is longer and pushes the height of that cell to be higher. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

something it's not right with your layout.

you say :`grid-row` but you use it as columns. the `Grid-cell` have nothing to do with columns, they are just random divs inside the column with class `grid-row` .

saying `I want to change the background color of the top row` you are not referring to any row in your html. there isn't one

i guess you mean that you want all the first `grid-cell`s to have background blue . so you need to remove paddings from the `grid-row` columns and add them instead to the `.grid-cell` .

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/pb08vw6c/1/)

```css
// .grid {
//   border: solid 1px #e7e7e7;
// }

// .grid__row {
//   display: flex;
//   background: whitesmoke;
// }

// .grid__item {
//   flex: 1;
//   padding: 12px;
//   border: solid 1px #e7e7e7;
// }

.Grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word !important;  
}
.Grid-row {
  //flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding:0;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-wrap: break-word !important; 
  
}
.Grid-cell {
   width: 100%;
   flex: 1;
   word-wrap: break-word !important;   
   min-width: 50%;
  padding:0 1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.Grid-cell:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: lightgray;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;   
}  

.Grid-row:first-child {
  background:dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.Grid-cell:first-child {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top:1em;
}
.Grid-cell:first-child {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id=event-data>
    Event Data Info Goes Here

</div>

<div id=event-history-view>
    <div class="Grid">
        <div class="Grid-row">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">1Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-row">
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-row">
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">2Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">3Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-row">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-row">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-row">
            <div class="Grid-cell">Change Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Brief Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Description</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Commentary</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Severity Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Ticker Type Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Code</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Disclosure Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Category Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Publish Mode Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Agreement Date</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Deletion Reason</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Updated By</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Status Name</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Commentary Approved</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Needs Secondary Approval</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Comments</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell">Event Approval Updated By</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label class="error" *ngIf="error">Error Loading Data {{"  " + errorMessage}}</label>
</div>
```

but i suggest you make your layout according to your requirements